# Не работает команда. Как исправить?

Tags: python

Нету ни ошибки, ни ответа...

Код:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True, aliases = ["квартира"])
async def apartment( ctx ):
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Ф.1.1.1', ctx.message.guild.roles)
    if role in user.roles:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Фото вашей квартиры:",
            description = 
                """
                **Улица Фарисаро**, 
                - дом **1**, этаж **1**, 
                - квартира **14**""",
            colour = discord.Colour.green()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Но...",
            description = 
                """
                **У вас ещё нету квартиры...**""",
            colour = discord.Colour.green()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А, надо было написать user = ctx.author.

Понял.